# Raspberry pi creating swap before HDD is mounted

Tags: mount, swap-space

I'm currently running Plex on a Raspberry pi 3 (Jessie, debian 8.0 32bit / Linux 4.9.35-v7+).

Lately I've noticed that Plex seems to be causing a great deal of Swap usage (possibly during housekeeping tasks at night).
I have tried moving the swap out over to the external HDD (to avoid SD card corruption)  connected to it through USB. However, it seems that `dphys-swapfile` runs **BEFORE** the HDD is mounted at boot so after a reboot swap is at 0 available.

Is there any way to ensure the swap file is created once mounting is done?

*NOTE*: The HDD is mounted through `fstab`

Comment: You can mount swap at any time, so try running `systemctl restart [or start] dphys-swapfile`.  If this works you could add something to `rc.local`.  You could also replace it with your own service that does the same thing only latter in the boot cycle, by copying and modifying the script to start as late as possible (I don't recommend modifying the script directly as that is the kind of thing which may get overwritten by updates).  I believe this is in `/etc/init.d`, so if you want to call it directly from so other script you could `/etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start`.

Comment: Your rc.local suggestion to restart dphys-swapfile worked great. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have the same problem and with `rc.local` I was not able to solve it. When I run it on startup `systemctl status rc.local.service` will give me the error that the code was exited with error while running it manually as `./rc.local` works fine.

Comment: ```
apt remove dphys-swapfile
``` will get rid of the whole package.